# SQL select is query is not working properly

Tags: sql

I am unable to apply a filter(where condition) on the query

```
SELECT A.Form_Id,
      B.CONTAINER_ID,
      A.FORM_DESC,
      A.FORM_TITLE,
      A.LAYOUT,
      A.TOTAL_COLUMNS,
      COUNT (*) Over () AS Total_Rows
      ROW_NUMBER () OVER ( ORDER BY CONTAINER_ID ASC ) ROWNM
    FROM FORM_DEFINITION A
    LEFT JOIN
      (SELECT CONTAINER_ID,FORM_ID FROM FORM_CONTAINER_DEFINITION
      ) B
    ON A.FORM_ID = B.FORM_ID
    AND ( ( UPPER(TRIM(A.FORM_ID)) LIKE '%'
      || UPPER(TRIM('FORM2'))
      ||'%' ) )
```

In the above code I applied filter like this

```
( ( UPPER(TRIM(A.FORM_ID)) LIKE '%'
      || UPPER(TRIM('FORM2'))
      ||'%' ) )
```

Except this part the query is giving all the info. This filter should show only 'FORM2' row.

But it is showing all the rows as normaly.
.
.
Could you resolve my issue....
.
.
Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are actually using.  The original tags of mysql and sql-server don't seem correct.

Comment: I am very new to stackoverflow, I will tag my correctly next time onwards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conditions on the first table in a `LEFT JOIN` need to go in the `WHERE` clause.  On the second table, in the `ON` clause.  Also, the subquery is not necessary.  So:

```
SELECT . ..
FROM FORM_DEFINITION A LEFT JOIN
     FORM_CONTAINER_DEFINITION B
     ON A.FORM_ID = B.FORM_ID
WHERE UPPER(TRIM(A.FORM_ID)) LIKE '%' || UPPER(TRIM('FORM2')) || '%';
```

The logic is actually simpler than the above rule.  A `LEFT JOIN` keeps all rows in the first table, regardless of the condition in the `ON` clause.  Matching rows get the values from the second table.  Non-matching rows get `NULL` values.

This is true even when the condition is on the first table.

Also, I would encourage you to use sensible aliases for tables rather than `A` and `B`.  I would suggest `FD` and `FCD` for these two tables.

Comment: You can do away with UPPER and TRIM functions on 'FORM2' in the WHERE clause. I don't see any reason for those two functions being applied on right side of the clause

Comment: @Incognito . . . My guess is that the constant `'FORM2'` is being provided through a variable, and the OP wants the trimming and upper casing.

Comment: Yes, in that case it would be needed.